# How to get a where clause using ngResource in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple service given here and I want to get a record(s) using a where clause, i.e. the endpoint would http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers?userName=anton

The service is:

```js
angular.
  module('shared.testUser').
  factory('TestUser', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/:id', {id:'@id'},//parameters
            {
                update: {
                      method: 'PUT' // To send the HTTP Put request when calling this custom update method.
                }

            });
    }
  ]);
```

And the controller code I have tried is:

```js
    self.checkUsersEntryDirection = function(){ //NOT WORKING
      self.testuser = TestUser.get({ username: 'anton' }, function() {
        console.log(angular.toJson(self.testuser));
      }); // get() returns a single entry
    }
```

The error I get is

> Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers)

Notice how it didn't add on the where clause.  I thought that any extra properties provided would be assigned as where clause items??

thanks

Comment: Your server is returning an array for the request and Angular is expecting a single object. Try `TestUser.query({username: 'anton'})` instead

Comment: Hi Phil, I thought like you and tried that too.  It returned all the records instead of the filtered record.

Comment: Then your server is ignoring the query parameters

Comment: I'll check this and get back to you

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  The API is not working as it should, thank you.